# How to load library before params statement in R Markdown or use expresion from some library to give default value to params

Tags: r

I'm trying to use params. My problem is that I want to assign to previous_working_day some default day using library bizdays.

````
title: "MyDocument"
author: "SomePerson"
date: !r Sys.Date()
output: html_document
params:
  previous_working_day: !r adjust.previous(Sys.Date()-1, cal)
---

```{r}
library(bizdays)
```
````

During kniting with parameters in GUI instead of date I have string
*adjust.previous(Sys.Date()-1, cal)*.
The reason is that there isn't loaded library earlier. But when I tried add library on the beginnig I get error. So this way that don't work:

````
```{r}
library(bizdays)
```
---
title: "MyDocument"
author: "SomePerson"
date: !r Sys.Date()
output: html_document
params:
  previous_working_day: !r adjust.previous(Sys.Date()-1, cal)
---
````

How I can deal with it to give previous_working_day some value when I need to use other library earlier?

Comment: try with the namespace `packagename::function` it's working :)

Comment: ... or just set it `!r NULL` and set it correctly in the first code block.